# Centering footer lists

Tags: html, css

I've been looking around for quite some time now trying to find a solution to this specific problem.

I have a footer  located outside the container  so that I could expand the footer across the page without it adhering to the parent div which has a width of 960px.

This has caused a problem when I attempt to create 3 columns of centered lists within the footer

I couldn't post all of the code I have gone through testing this, but this is what I have at the moment-

CSS

```
#footer {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
background-color:grey;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;}
```

Html:

```
        <div id="footer">
        <div class="col">
        <h2>recent entries</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <h2>recent comments</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
          <h2>featured on</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="#'">3 Column Footer Example</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is a jsfiddle of the current situation (mind that the footer width spans the entire page and is located outside of content container)

http://jsfiddle.net/2DUaZ/

I'm a novice, so it makes it hard for me to distinguish exactly how to center these lists in parallel.

I know you can't center floats exactly, so I thought absolute positioning would be the solution, but I've only found dead ends so far.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**JSFIddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2DUaZ/6/)

Wouldn't adding this work?:

```
#footer div {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, got there before me. +1 that's the way I would do it.

Comment: Darn you and your speed! :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer(didn't see you were first), it's working great! oop, hang on. The 33% width messed it up. I should have explained that I wanted the content (in the footer) within 960px, so it was beneath the content, while not extending outside the width of the content (apart from BG)

Comment: You would need to wrap the `.col` column divs in another centered div with a set width/max-width: See: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2DUaZ/10/

Comment: I just figured that out myself.So silly! Once again I have underestimated the power of divs. Thanks Paulie, big help.

Answer (score 1):

You can float them left maybe?

```
.col {
   float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DUaZ/4/

and if you want to center them, can use another div holder, which you can center with:

```
margin: auto auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DUaZ/7/

Comment: @Simonas B. 
It seems to work in jsfiddle like that, but when scaled to a 1600px width screen, the columns are all far to the left of center. Since my footer isn't the same width as the content, they go much further left than they would if the footer width were 960px also.

Comment: `margin: auto auto;` doesn't center them. Not in your fiddle anyways. You would need to give them `width: 33.3%`

Comment: @SimonasB I did say that in my comment but the point is... You didn't.

Comment: I did that on fiddle didn't I?

Comment: @SimonasB. Nope. You did for the container but not the `col`.

Comment: Dude relax, he/she chose your answer :)

Comment: @SimonasB. Huh? Im trying to help you complete your answer. I don't mind who gets the correct answer from the OP. This sites about learning and helping.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple:

### CSS:

```
#footer div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2DUaZ/8/)

Comment: Saint. Worked perfectly. I wish I understood why though.

Comment: I was going to say Paulie_D got it just before me. Look up about `inline-block`. Mess around with it and you will understand.

Comment: Technically, your answer is closest to correct, but it was only because I omitted some details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly

```
.col, .col2, .col3 {
float: inline-block; 
width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: ... theres already 2 answers with this. Don't think we need a third.

Comment: After submitting my answer I come to know that you have already submitted. Sorry!!!